# Implementing Yelp API Into iPhone App

Tags: ios, swift, yelp

I am trying to integrate Yelp's APIs for developers into my iPhone Application. I have taken the Objective-C Code from https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/ and I have simply dragged the files into my existing Xcode project. I input my token and keys, and I have several errors, most referring to ARC Semantics.

I am very new to iOS development and I am not familiar with api integration, so I was wondering what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!